# How does count method works in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a hard time understanding the following code segment from the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count):

```
a = "hello world"
a.count "lo"                   #=> 5
a.count "lo", "o"              #=> 2
a.count "hello", "^l"          #=> 4
a.count "ej-m"                 #=> 4

"hello^world".count "\\^aeiou" #=> 4
"hello-world".count "a\\-eo"   #=> 4
```

especially this code `a.count "ej-m"`. Can anyone please explain how it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just imagine the "pattern" strings as wrapped by `[` and `]` from regex syntax, that are matched against each character.

So, if we break `a = "hello world"` into characters:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
[2] pry(main)> a.split('')
=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```

And convert "ej-m" to regex wrapped with `[` and `]` we get `/[ej-m]/` - which means either `'e'` or any character from `'j'` to `'m'`(including both):

```
[3] pry(main)> a.split('').select{|c| c=~ /[ej-m]/}
=> ["e", "l", "l", "l"]
```

We got 4 matches - which is also the result you get. Essensially `a.count "ej-m"` is equivalent to:

```
[4] pry(main)> a.split('').count{|c| c=~ /[ej-m]/}
=> 4
```

Multiple arguments to the method are just `and` between the matches:

```
[5] pry(main)> a.split('').count{|c| c =~ /[hello]/ and c =~ /[^l]/}
=> 4
```

Comment: I distinctly remember leaving a comment last time that said something like, "'- which means either 'e' or any character from 'j' to 'm'(including both):' made it clear to me. Thank you so much" Dunno how it got deleted.

Answer (score 2):

`The sequence c1-c2 means all characters between c1 and c2.`
So you are providing a range, basically it counts which characters are in that range (>= c1 && <= c2)
i.e:

```
a = "hello world"
a.count "a-z"
=> 10 
a.count "o-w"
=> 4  #(o, o, r, w)
a.count "e-l"
=> 5  #(h, e, l, l, l)
```

Answer (score 2):

We find that

```
"hello world".count("ej-m")       #=> 4 (_ell_____l_)
```

Examine the doc for [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count) carefully.

Here is how `count` might be implemented to deal with patterns that closely resemble the pattern `"ej-m"`.

```
def count_letters(str, pattern) 
  idx = pattern[1..-2].index('-')
  if idx
    idx += 1
    before, after = pattern[idx-1], pattern[idx+1]
    pattern[idx-1..idx+1] = (before..after).to_a.join
  end
  str.each_char.sum { |c| pattern.include?(c) ? 1 : 0 }
end

count_letters(str, pattern)       #=> 4 (_ell_____l_)
```

However, `String#count` must also do the following.

*Allow for multiple ranges in the pattern*

```
"hello1world".count("e0-9j-mv-x") #=> 6 (_ell__1_w__l_)
```

*If the pattern begins with the character `'^'`count the number of characters that do not match the remainder of the pattern*

```
"hello world".count("^ej-m")      #=> 7 (h___o*wor_d) * = space to count
"hello^world".count("e^j-m")      #=> 5 (_ell_^___l_)
"hello world".count("\^ej-m")     #=> 7 (h___o*wor_d) * = space to count
```

Note that escaping `'^'` at the beginning of the string makes no difference.

*Match a hyphen*

```
"hello-world".count("ej-m-")      #=> 5 (_ell_-___l_)
"hello-world".count("-ej-m")      #=> 5 (_ell_-___l_)
"hello-world".count("ej\-m")      #=> 4 (_ell____l_)
```

Note that escaping a hyphen that is not the first or last character of the pattern makes no difference.

*Match a backslash*

```
'hello\world'.count("ej-m\\")     #=> 5 (_ell_\___l_)
'hello\world'.count("\\ej-m")     #=> 4 (_ell____l_)
```

Note that a backslash at the beginning of a string is disregarded.

Some of the above results (Ruby v2.4) do not seem to be consistent with the documentation.

Comment: Very detailed and useful explanation. Thank you very much.